# Functions in Android?

Tags: android, function, methods

I am relatively new to programming for Androids and I have a back ground in PHP. I have written a script that at the moment pulls a single row from a database and populates two buttons and a textview. I know what to have another button that when clicked queries the database again and changes the buttons and textviews.

I'm guessing I need to create a function that when the button is clicked it runs the query I already have and the setText of each element again.

How do I create a function I can pass variables to and run from wherever.

Comment: It would help to see the code you have written so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will likely end up simply setting the Button's onClickListener, which every view has. For example:

```
Button b = new Button();
b.setOnClickListener(fireAway)
```

and somewhere else...

```
private OnClickListener fireAway = new OnClickListener(){
          updatestuff()     
};

public void updateStuff(){
      queryDb();
      updateViews();
}
```

You might want to keep references to your views.

```
private TextView textView;
private Button button;
```

But the take away is each Button/TextView is a subclass of View, and both have built in listener functionality for clicks, touches, etc., so what you are trying to implement will be a breeze once you learn more.

Only complication I can see is that Views can ONLY be... eh, modified or handled or something by the thread that created the View hierarchy.

In other words, if you start off in an Activity and 'inflate', or create all your views and layouts, you will need to keep a reference to the Thread's handler if you want to man handle the views from another thread.

```
Handler viewHandler = new Handler(); // this will get you a vanilla handler to the thread that is executing that code, least I think.
```

Sorry for the doubt; I too am still learning.

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Java is OO so there aren't functions. Rather there are methods and what I would suggest doing is taking a look at the handling UI events section of the documentation: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html